# Mongoose - Code Outside of Query Executed First

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using Node JS and am making a request to my MongoDB server. The problem is the 2 console logs outside of my Data.findOne() seem to be executed before the contents in the query.

```
Data.findOne({_id: "---"}, (err, docs) => {
    item1 = docs.projects[1]
    item2 = docs.projects[2]
    console.log(item1)
    console.log(item2)
})
console.log(item1)
console.log(item2)
```

This is causing errors later on in my code as it's trying to access the contents in item1 and item2 but they are undefined. It's not an issue of whether or not the object actually exists because the logs inside the function return objects, it's just that the contents of the functions are executed at the wrong time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use promise style instead of call back style.

```
const SomeFunction = async() => {
 try {
    const docs = await Data.findOne({_id: "---"}).lean()
    const item1 = docs.projects[1]
    const item2 = docs.projects[2]
    console.log(item1)
    console.log(item2)
 } catch(err) {
      console.log(error)
 }
}
```

Bonus: [Faster Query with lean()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html)

Comment: I tried implementing what you did by copying that function then calling it right under using `SomeFunction()` but when I follow it with `console.log(item1); console.log(item2)`, it still seems to be executing the logs outside of the function, then the logs inside. I know this because it logs 2 empty objects (from the console logs outside), then logs 2 objects with data (the 2 console logs inside the function)

Comment: You have to use await/async.  await means wait for the promise to return. Notice i have the word `await` infront fo. Data.findOne. Same thing when you call `SomeFunction`, you need to use `await SomeFunction()`.  If you don't use await, then the 2 console.log will execute before the promise is returned.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await